# How can i clear my Google appengine Datastore using JPA QUERY?

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore, jpql

I`m trying to clear my datastore, dynamically in a servlet, using Jquery.
but i cant find any API for clear all tables automatically, so i`m trying to erase all rows from all tables like this:

```
EntityManager em = emfInstance.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
String q = String.format("DELETE FROM " + className + " WHERE key IS NOT NULL");        
Query jquery = em.createQuery(q);
jquery.executeUpdate();
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

but i cant compare key with NULL, besides GAE shows the id as ID/Name on dashboard, and call it as key in code.

does any one knows how to clear all data store? note the local one, the deployed one!

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use JPQL DELETE to do this

```
Query q = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM MyClass m");
q.executeUpdate();
```